# Connect to VM Behind Network Security Group

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to use Azure Data Factory on MySQL Database that is being run on a VM behind NSG. I'm able to connect to it via Public IP when NSG is allowing public access on port 3306, which shouldn't be used in production. Yet, I'm not able to connect to via Private IP despite having set up a private endpoint.
Why is it not working?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Make sure that SHIR is installed in the same network where databse is present.Test your datastore connection in SHIR.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a private endpoint to ADF just changes the networking for connecting to the front door of ADF. It has no impact on how ADF connects to other services such as MySQL.

I would suggest you should create a new [Self-Hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) on the same VNET (or a peered VNET) which is allowed to connect to MySQL. Then change the ADF linked service for MySQL to use the new SHIR.

Comment: Installing additional software seems weird. Azure Data Factory is able to connect to my database via Public IP, but not via Private IP. What if I was using MySQL DB SaaS that is not publicly accessible and there is no option to install software on it?

Comment: We are actually going to move to IaaS Azure Database for MySQL - Flexible Server and there is no option to install software there.